# Get NodeCopter data from client just once?

Tags: node.js

I would like to get the data from a client (AR.Drone 2.0) just once and them store it in a variable to be printed. I have used:

```
client.on('navdata', console.log);
```

however, when I execute this command data is printed more than once and I have to stop the script to stop this process. How can I get the data just once and store it in a variable.

Comment: maybe use [client.`once()`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_once_event_listener) instead?

Comment: It worked :). Thank you so much, but I would like to store this data into a variable because I need to use some of the data that have been read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Client** object inherits **EventEmitter**, so you should be able to use [`once()`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_once_event_listener) to listen for **navdata** event only once. To store the emitted value to a variable you can do something like:

```
var _navData;
// ...
client.once('navdata', function (navData) {
    _navData = navData;
});
```

---

**Update**

Regarding to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768938/get-nodecopter-data-from-client-just-once/30769036#comment49590121_30769036), I suggest you to declare a function that gets a **navdata** object as an argument and pass that function to `client.once()`:

```
var doSomethingWithNavData = function doSomethingWithNavData(navData) {
    console.log(navData);
    // do what ever you want to do with navData...
}

client.once('navdata', doSomethingWithNavData);
```

Comment: after your code I have added `console.log(_navData);`, and I get `undefined`.

Comment: The code executes asynchronously, that's why Client emits the navdata event to its listeners, try logging the value in client.once callback

Comment: Well, I am completely new to NodeJS, so I have no idea how to get this done. Could you give me a clue?

Answer (score 1):

There are two [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html) methods for adding listeners: [`.on()`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_event_listener) and [`.once()`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_once_event_listener).

- [`.on()`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_event_listener) actively listens and catches events until [`.removeListener()`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_removelistener_event_listener) or [`.removeAllListeners()`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_removealllisteners_event_listener) are called to remove the listener.
- [`.once()`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_once_event_listener) listens for the **next event** and **removes itself automatically** (effectively running *once*), unless `.removeListener()` or `.removeAllListeners()` are called to remove it before it does.